# Is naming a file with two dots such as "..file" documented to move the file to the parent directory, or is this a bug?

Tags: macos-big-sur

If I name a file something like "..filename" it moves the file to the parent directory. I'm a security researcher and this is something I wasn't expecting. Seems like it's a bug but I haven't been able to find much info about it so I was hoping somewhere here could let me know if this is documented behavior or not. Thanks.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you do when you "name a file". I don't have MAC, but on Linux I don't see such a behavior, and MAC shouldn't be different from Linux in this aspect.

Comment: @Dmitry I thought I described it pretty well but, here you go. You literally name a file “..filenamehere” without the quotes. So you could run the command `touch ..newfile` Without the back ticks and it’ll end up in the parent directory.